# A weird problem with pdfpages and table of contents

Tags: pdfpages

Never happened to me before: I'm trying to insert a pdf file using pdfpages and also create a TOC entry as a chapter. But the first page of the inserted file then overlaps with the second page. No such problem if I don't use tableofcontents or if the inclusion in TOC is at the level of sections. MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[noautoscale=false,nup=1x2,pages={1-},landscape=true,addtotoc={1,chapter,1,{PDF file included},pdffile}]{PDFfile}
\end{document}
```

If I replace "chapter" with "secton", the problem disappears (but the TOC line is unsatisfactory). If the first number in addtotoc is 3 or above, the problem disappears (but the result is unsatisfactory).

Any ideas? Unfortunately, I don't have a second machine here to test if this is something specific to my installation.

Comment: I have managed to isolate the problem with pdfpages. The issue doesn't exist, and everything compiles as expected with the version as late as v0.5f (from 2016). Not sure how to deal with it other than by using this older version.

Comment: @egreg I get a problem. When I use `example-image-a4-numbered` as pdf page 1 and 2 are gone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh! I didn't check the number of pages. I'll retract my comment.

Comment: Just a note: Andreas Matthias, the author and current maintainer of `pdfpages` has fixed this in `pdfpages` 0.5u (2022-01-29). Check the [CTAN Announcement](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/zqB8jJNvfw0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why it happens. Anyway, a workaround seems to be adding something invisible between the TOC and the included file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mbox{}

\includepdf[
  noautoscale=false,
  nup=1x2,
  pages=-,
  landscape=true,
  addtotoc={1,chapter,0,{PDF file included},pdffile}
]{\jobname fake}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The “fake” file has eight pages.

Comment: it happens as pdfpages issues \@chapter in the middle of the code, and then the `{\setbox\z@\lastbox}` from `\@afterheading` eats the last box away. It works if one e.g. use `\usepackage{indentfirst}`. Looks like a bug that should be reported to pdfpages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for identifying this issue.